# Finding commits with a given prefix using libgit

Tags: git, rust, commit, git-commit, libgit2

How do I get the commit corresponding to the hash prefix string `"r23e23"` using libgit2?

A [git2-rs](https://crates.io/crates/git2) based solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git_revparse_*` methods can be used for this task.

For `git2-rs`, [`Repository::revparse_single`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.11.0/git2/struct.Repository.html#method.revparse_single) can be used to get the git object corresponding to a hash, which then can be converted to a commit.

Comment: This is barely an answer. Not very helpful for anyone who is looking for a solution. Please expand it